# sending props form child to parent returning TypeError: _this.props.removeEl is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

im sending a li item from currencyDropdown.js to panelDropdown.js component but it's returning that prop is not a function

currencyDropdown.js

```
method

setCurrency = (currency) => {
  this.props.dropCurrency(currency);
}

<div className="all_currrency">
  <ul>
    {
      this.props.currencies.map((currency) => (

        <li key={currency.name} onClick={() => {
          this.setCurrency(currency)
        }}>
          <div className="currenct_item">
            <div className="currency_flag">
              <img src={currency.flag} alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div className="currency_name">
              <span>{currency.name}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      ))
    } </ul>
</div>
```

panelDropdown.js

```
method

setCurrency = (currency) => {
  this.setState({currentCurr: currency.name, currentFlag: currency.flag});
  this.props.removeEl(currency); // this is giving the error removeEl is not a function
}


<CurrencyItems dropCurrency={this.setCurrency} currencies={this.props.all_currencies}/>
```

Comment: Are these inside render methods?

Comment: so i have two panelDropdown.js component and i have setted on only one removeEl and i was running code on other one that i have not set removeEl so i added to it and it's fixed now

Comment: Link the full code for both components, so we have full context